# In Rails, how do you write a finder with "where" that compares two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I’m using Rails 4.2.  I have a model with these date time attributes

```
submitted_at
created_at
```

How do I write a finder method that returns all the models where the submitted_at field occurs chronologically before the created_at field?  I tried this

```
MyModel.where(:submitted_at < :created_at)
```

But that is returning everything in my database, even items that don’t match.

Comment: Why would submitted_at happen before created_at? Usually created_at is that timestamp that is set automatically when a record is saved.

Comment: There in lies the great mystery

Comment: `MyModel.where(MyModel.arel_table[:submitted_at].lt(MyModel.arel_table[:created_at]))`. Also I can see many times where submitted may predate creation e.g. manual entry, data polling, importation, etc. in these cases data can absolutely exist in some other form prior to being created in the system.

Comment: @engineersmnky I might be possible to predate created_at but, IMO it's very confusing. Even if you import manually, I'd say they should be ... equal.

Comment: @razvans very well but if I send you a file today then I submitted it today. If you don't import it until next week it does not change when I submitted it. I have helped create multiple systems that do batch processing where the processing of a file was delayed for timing purposes however the actual submission date and time were retained for posterity and thus the "submission date" always predated the auto populated created_at

Comment: @engineersmnky Fair point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where(:submitted_at < :created_at)` is actually `where(false)`. When you compare two symbols with the lt/gt operators you're actually just comparing them alphabetically:

```
:a < :b # true
:c > :b # true
```

`where(false)` or any other argument thats [blank?](https://blog.arkency.com/2017/07/nil-empty-blank-ruby-rails-difference/) just returns an "unscoped" relation for chaining.

The ActiveRecord query interface doesn't really have a straight forward way to compare columns like this.

You either use a SQL string:

```
Resource.where('resources.submitted_at < resources.created_at')
```

Or use Arel to create the query:

```
r = Resource.arel_table
Resource.where(r[:submitted_at].lt(r[:created_at]))
```

The results are exactly the same but the Arel solution is arguably more portable and avoids hardcoding the table name (or creating an ambigeous query).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.to_sql` to see what query is generated.

For yours it looks like this:

```
Resource.where(:submitted_at < :created_at).to_sql 
# => SELECT `resources`.* FROM `resources`
```

If you update like below, you will get some results:

```
Resource.where('submitted_at < created_at')
# => SELECT * FROM `resources` WHERE (submitted_at < created_at)
```

Comment: This prints out sql but how do you actually print out results in the Rails console?

Comment: If you're planing on using this in a scope then using `created_at` without specifying the table name is bound to lead to an ambigeous query as its on almost every table in the average rails app.

Comment: Updated. Just remove `.to_sql`, it was just to see it works. YOu can add `.count`, `.first`, etc.

Comment: @max You are right if you do joins.

Comment: Well a rule of thumb when writing a scope is really that you don't know how it will be used down the road. Be specific.

Comment: @max I agree with you but there's no scope involved. OP just wants to test something in the console :).